# Techniques to keep database schema up to date

Tags: database, schema

I know two techniques to keep database schema up to date for all developers.

One is rails migrations. And the other is Hibernate's SchemaUpdate.

Can you review more techniques to keep the DB schema up to date?

Comment: look into Liquibase, it's language agnostic.

Comment: Some scenario is: there is some application, this application have a database, but this database changes while the application developed and updated, you need to maintain the changes of the schema when updating this application to new versions and maintain the old data.. is it the scenario you are talking about?

Comment: @MSS, Yes. And specifically, there are many people working on different parts of the application. And we don't want the application to fail if I updated my DB and forgot to tell you to update the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think its very hard to find  a ready made, magical tool that maintain your schema changes, i think its not hard to implement your custom tool and design the updates incrementally and make your own versioning system of the database.

My suggestion (and i do that) is to make a small updater tool that take the update scripts from the new version of the application and apply the required updates depending on the previous DB version that is saved somewhere, the update scripts should be robust and well-written and don't make a damage for the old data.
Because DDL changes are not inversable (You can't use transactions) i suggest to take a backup for the database before the update process and restore it if the update failed or delete it.

Comment: I'd rather use an existing tools to manage that (such as rails migrations) instead of reinventing the wheel myself. Thus I want recommendation of tools that does similar things. To see many different approaches of managing DDL changes.